# C# / Mono: Why is the RemoteEndPoint of my TcpClient Socket "null"?

Tags: c#, mono, tcpclient

I ran into a problem where a newly accepted TcpClient has no RemoteEndPoint although the underlying Socket is connected. There are a few times (~ 5% of connections) where the RemoteEndPoint property is set, but that is not very helpful. The setup is always the same, so are the sent packages. Did anybody of you had the same issue?

[image]